# How to toggle table rows on and off

Tags: jquery, html, xslt

I am currently toggling some table rows in my XSLT (html) xml style sheets.

I have 6 rows I hide 3 to begin with then on a onClick command I would like to hide 1 row and open 3 others.

This is what it looks like

**on load xml**

```
first row - Talents_Passive | Talent/Talent_Cost
second row - Prerequisite
third row - Action / Range / Cost
seventh row - Description
```

**on click** // should be able to toggle between the two with my jQuery

```
first row - Talents_Passive | Talent/Talent_Cost
second row - Prerequisite
fourth row - Action
fifth row - Range
Sixth row - Cost
seventh row - Description
```

this is what my code looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/Collection">
     <html>
     <header>

        <script type ="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" ></script>
        <script>
            <!-- insert toggling here -->


        function toggle_it(itemID){ 
      // Toggle visibility between none and inline 
      if ((document.getElementById(itemID).style.display == 'none')) 
      { 
        document.getElementById(itemID).style.display = 'inline'; 
      } else { 
        document.getElementById(itemID).style.display = 'none'; 
      } 
  } 

        </script>
    </header>
     <body>

     <!-- header -->
     <table border="0" width="550" height="25">
        <tr>
            <td>
            <div style="font-family:Calibri, Arial; font-size:15pt">
            Passive Talents
            </div>
            </td>
         </tr>      
     </table>

     <!-- Passive Talent loop -->
        <xsl:for-each select="Talents_Passive">
        <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()"/>
        <div style="font-family:Calibri, Arial; font-size:5pt">
        <xsl:if test="Talent != ''">
            <table border="0" width="550">

                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#A0A0A0" width="80%">
                        <a href="#" onClick="toggle_it('{$i}')">  <b id="toggle"><xsl:value-of select="Talent"/></b></a></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#A0A0A0" width="20%" align="center">
                        <xsl:value-of select="Talent_Cost"/><xsl:text>  -  </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="Talent_Type"/></td>
                 </tr>

                 <xsl:if test="Prerequisite != ''">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><b>Prerequisite: </b><xsl:value-of select="Prerequisite"/></td>
                </tr>
                </xsl:if>

                 <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#C0C0C0" id="{$i}" style="display:inline;"> 
                    <xsl:if test="Action != ''">
                        <b>Action: </b><xsl:value-of select="Action"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="Range != ''">
                        <xsl:text>    </xsl:text> <b>Range: </b><xsl:value-of select="Range"/> 
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="Cost != ''">
                        <xsl:text>    </xsl:text> <b>Cost: </b><xsl:value-of select="Cost"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                    </td>
                 </tr>  

                <xsl:if test="Action != ''">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#E0E0E0" id="{$i}" style="display:none;"><b>Action: </b><xsl:value-of select="Action"/></td>
                </tr>
                </xsl:if>

                <xsl:if test="Range != ''">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#E0E0E0" id="{$i}" style="display:none;"><b>Range: </b><xsl:value-of select="Range"/></td>
                </tr>
                </xsl:if>

                <xsl:if test="Cost != ''">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#E0E0E0" id="{$i}" style="display:none;"><b>Cost: </b><xsl:value-of select="Cost"/></td>
                </tr>
                </xsl:if>

                <xsl:if test="Description != ''">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#EBEBEB"><b>Description: </b><xsl:value-of select="Description"/></td>
                </tr>
                </xsl:if>

            </table>
        </xsl:if>
        </div>
     </xsl:for-each>
     </body>
     </html>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

currently what happens is the thrid row hides when the onClick event is actioned but rows four, five and six do not show...

effective I want row two to swap plaes with rows four, five and six.. any help would be appreciated.

I think this is the cause of my troubles...

```
<script>
                <!-- insert toggling here -->


            function toggle_it(itemID){ 
          // Toggle visibility between none and inline 
          if ((document.getElementById(itemID).style.display == 'none')) 
          { 
            document.getElementById(itemID).style.display = 'inline'; 
          } else { 
            document.getElementById(itemID).style.display = 'none'; 
          } 
      } 

            </script>
```

but I cannot figure out why it wont toggle like I planned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you do not have unique id's in your generated html.

Your have to add a prefix to  each of your id's. E.g.:

```
<td colspan="2" bgcolor="#C0C0C0" id="action_{$i}" style="display:inline;"> 
<td colspan="2" bgcolor="#E0E0E0" id="x_{$i}" style="display:none;">
<td colspan="2" bgcolor="#E0E0E0" id="y_{$i}" style="display:none;">
<td colspan="2" bgcolor="#E0E0E0" id="z_{$i}" style="display:none;">
```

And change your javascript function to something like:

```
    function toggle_it_withId(itemID){ 
  // Toggle visibility between none and inline 
      if ((document.getElementById(itemID).style.display == 'none')) 
      { 
        document.getElementById(itemID).style.display = 'inline'; 
      } else { 
        document.getElementById(itemID).style.display = 'none'; 
      } 
  }

    function toggle_it(id_nr)
    { 
        toggle_it_withId("action_" + id_nr);
        toggle_it_withId("x_" +id_nr);
        toggle_it_withId("y_" +id_nr);
        toggle_it_withId("z_" +id_nr);
      }
```

But this could be even easier with jquery slectors

Update (one posibility) how to do this whith jquery:

- Add an unique id to you talent table.

  ```
  <table border="0" width="550" id="talenttable_{id}" >
  ```
- Add class attributes to your row' you like to toggle.  Something like details for the hidden ones and overview for open ones.

  ```
  <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#C0C0C0" class="overview" style="display:inline;">
  <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#E0E0E0" class="details" style="display:none;">
  ```
- Change the your toggle function to something like:

  ```
   function toggle_it(id_nr)
   { 
     $('#talenttable_'+ id_nr + ' .details').toggle();
     $('#talenttable_'+ id_nr + ' .overview').toggle();
    }
  ```
- Optional you can also get rid of the bgcolor and style attributes and put this information into  the classes.

Comment: merp.. trying to get this to work but dosnt seem to be.. how do I define my on click event?... I just want to use the one on click event..  is that possible..  i dont really get the second function there.

Comment: The onclick handler should stay as it was: `onClick="toggle_it('{$i}')">`

Comment: woops I was putting the X_ inside the {} in the table code.. so thats why it was breaking... so took it outside and it worked perfect.

Comment: @HurkNburkS: Update do give you an idea how it could work with jquery.